# Pre-rendering a 3D scene programmatically

Tags: 3d, rendering

For a level generator for a computer game, I need a way to programmatically render a 3D scene. To be more precise, I don't mean 3D-APIs like OpenGL or Direct3D, the scene shouldn't be rendered at runtime of the game, but rather the scene should be rendered off-line for later use.

I know of RenderMan, but I'd be interested if there are other alternatives. Concerning RenderMan, is this a suitable tool for this purpose at all?

Could a 3D scene be described using COLLADA and fed into a renderer?

Thanks
Johannes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of options. Here's three:

- [3DSMax](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) - pricey
- [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) - free
- [POVRay](http://www.povray.org/) - free

Comment: POVray is probably the best option to generate the scene since it works with simple text files for scene description.

Comment: However, a text file is the least user friendly way of designing a scene to be rendered though.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes, rendering offline images is what RenderMan is for.  Blizzard is an example of a game company that uses it for that purpose.  And yes, you could also export to another scene format like COLLADA and use a different renderer.  There's the matter of authoring a scene and then rendering it.  Renderers do operate on scene files, which may be in ascii format, and of course you don't want to write one by hand.  Maybe you're exporting the scene from a game engine or level editor?  Or else you'll want to create it in a modeling/animation package like Maya, Houdini, Max, Sketchup, Blender, etc.  These packages have various plug-in exporters and renderers.  The term RenderMan is used to refer to a scene description specification, like COLLADA, and it can also refer specifically to Pixar's renderer, which accepts the RenderMan format.  Several other renderers also accept the RenderMan format, and some are even free, like Pixie.  Picking a modeling package and renderer depends on your budget and requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess. If what you mean by off-line rendering is to get something that real-time rendering is hard to achieve for all, especially in game mode, like sub-surface scattering, soft shadow, anti-aliasing, more heavy-computing filtering, and global illumination, you can go for what Skizz and Tim suggested. And I will also recommend for [pbrt](http://pbrt.org/).

But, it all depends on what context and what you like to do then. Something like **how do you handle and get 3D objects and environment imported into the renderer?**, **what's your shading script/language?**, **what kind of rendered results would you need? Some background images? Or several rendered-out high-quality textures with GI embedded?**, etc.